# C# MVC IIS long running requests

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have an C# MVC app. And one of the calls I know will take like 12 hours, I'm generating some reports.

I want to know if the IIS will keep the process running this long. 
If I'll do it async will it run and somehow put it away and let him run for this long?

Comment: Take a look at Hangfire (https://www.hangfire.io). This is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, this is a very poor practice. Your app pool may be recycled for many reasons outside of your control.
You would greatly benefit from processing this in an external process and then providing the user the results via IIS.

However, starting .net 4.5.2 (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2014/05/05/announcing-the-net-framework-4-5-2/) you can use the `HostingEnvironment.QueueBackgroundWorkItem` API.
The idea behind this is that the IIS will try to finish this work in case of a graceful shutdown of the app pool.

Comment: so as long as the app pool is running it will run?

Comment: Yes. but you need to understand that if the user mashes that button then you may end up with 100% cpu usage very quickly

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the report must be using something like SSRS. Why don't you create a batch job at the backend to run the reports at a specified time. Update a table with the status of the report and just poll the status at the front end. when Ready just download it. Imagine if your report had been running for 6 hours and it's reliant on the website being up. If someone re-starts the website that's 6 hours of processing gone.

Comment: yep that was my second though. I think I will go with this.